# Kramers' Degeneracy and Geometric Symmetries

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-reversal-symmetry, stochastic-processes, randomness

I am currently reading the third edition of 'Quantum Signatures of Chaos' by Fritz Haake and trying to work through section 2.7 (Titled "Kramers' Degeneracy and Geometric Symmetries"). I am having some trouble trying to prove equation 2.7.2 which shows the action of rotation operators on parity eigenstates. I have copied the relevant page below and equation 2.7.2 reads:

> $$R_x\left| n\pm \right> = \pm i\left|n\pm\right>$$

By the theorem of compatible observable there exists a mutual set of eigenstates for the parity and rotation operator as they commute so I would assume that the $\left|n\pm\right>$ states correspond to this mutual eigenbasis ordered by some arbitrary parameter, $n$, but that is just an educated guess. Assuming that is the case I don't know how to show that eigenvalue of the rotation operator on the $\left|n\pm\right>$ state is $\pm i$. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that kind of a definition for a rotation of $\pi$.

Comment: Having thought about it a bit more, I think you are right because it has to be an eigenvalue of R_x and m must be half integer  so R_x on a half integer x state must yield plus/minus i. However, how do you show that the plus/minus i correspond to positive/negative parity respectively (it certainly seems right but it is not shown) I cannot find anything treating the parity of total angular momentum eigenstates (only orbital angular momentum). Cheers.